# How to create Runtime Component from C/C++ project

Tags: c++, runtime, components, store

I have a project written in C++ that converts a LaTeX formula to a `.gif` image and I want to use this project as a component in my C# Windows Store application.
How can I do this?

I [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441569.aspx) but do not understand it. If it is global, what about simple tasks? Is it easy?

I use Mathtex from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11406/Enable-Your-Users-to-Write-Math-Equations-in-Your)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, just create the C++ project as a **Windows Runtime Component** project or something similar, build it, and add it as a reference from the C# project.

Remember that you need to use C++/CX in order to create classes that can be consumed from C# in a Windows Store app. C++/CX is similar to C++/CLI (managed C++), except that C++/CX is unmanaged and for Windows Store apps, and C++/CLI is managed and for desktop apps. Either way, a normal C++ class can never be consumed from C# (unless it's a COM class, but that's a topic for another discussion).